# Where do my autocompletion colors come from?

Tags: 18.04, bash, gnome-terminal, colors, zsh

When I `ls` in a directory, the colors are printed as in the top example. These colors are controlled with *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Colors* → *Palette*, which I have set to Solarized.

However, I have no idea why my autocompletion colors are completely different, as seen in the bottom example. Where do I set those? I use `zsh`, but had the same issue in `bash`, too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1563#issuecomment-26591369), add the following in your `.zshrc` file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors "${(@s.:.)LS_COLORS}"
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

About the `ls` colors, I'm quoting [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94306/322816) answer from [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

> `ls` takes its color settings from the environment variable `LS_COLORS`. `dircolors` is merely a convenient way to generate this environment variable. To have this environment variable take effect system-wide, put it in your shell's startup file.

You can read more about `dircolors` [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors).

Comment: This is it. The default colors are the default `dircolors` settings when no custom config file is provided. This seems (at least on my machine) incidentally to be the same color set that `ls` uses when I manually `unset LS_COLORS`, which got me confused.