# cd color highlighting

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd-command

I am using Ubuntu in WSL2 and there is some annoying highlighting of folders. I managed to solve the highlighting when using `ls` via this tutorial: https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/06/wsl-ls-folder-highlight/

Setup: Windows Terminal, zsh shell in linux set up via oh-my-zsh and with zsh-autosuggestions, zsh-syntax-highlighting and autojump in terms of plugins.

However, I get the same rubbish highlighting when using `cd` + <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to get rid of it, as well?

Comment: I am using Windows terminal and zsh with oh-my-zsh. In terms of plugins, I have zsh-autosuggestions, zsh-syntax-highlighting and autojump.

Comment: The tutorial you linked appears to be for bash, whereas you appear to be using zsh. I don't know how oh-my-zsh does it, but the default `~/.zshrc` sets `LS_COLORS` via a call to `eval "$(dircolors -b)"` and then applies that to completions using `zstyle`. See for example [Where do my autocompletion colors come from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174503/where-do-my-autocompletion-colors-come-from)

Comment: You are true, however, even though the tutorial is made for bash, it helps with ls output but not with cd autocompletion

Comment: In addition, the tutorial you provided unfortunately does not work, No change